# How to stop auto formatting on commit VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a particular workspace that for whatever reason auto formats on commit. I have disabled prettier and eslint and it still does this. Are there any settings or plugins that cause this to happen?

Thanks

Comment: Check to see if this particular repo has any git hooks associated with it.

Comment: That was it, thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be caused by a Git hook triggering. Check the `.git/hooks` folder for any file not ending in `.sample` and remove or edit as needed.

*Credit to [Dan Forbes's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56068381/how-to-stop-auto-formatting-on-commit-vs-code#comment98776479_56068381).*